# Picking several lists of elements from a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

## Picking several lists of elements from a ndarray

Hello,

On Python using numpy, I have a ndarray `a = np.array([1,2,3])` and a list `b = [[0,2],[1]]`
I'd like to get `c = [[1,3],[2]]` efficiently but I don't find the solution.

I tried `c = a[b]` but get `"IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed"`

I tried to get `a_bis = np.tile(a, (2,1))`
Then `c = a_bis[b]` but `"IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2"`

`c = [a[b_] for b_ in b]` works but it looks not efficient.

I don't really know what to try next

Comment: "Looks like not efficient" is tough to answer. What are your expectations?

Comment: Not using the Python 'for' ? Using only numpy.
I don't know if it is possible

Comment: Since the lists differ in length as do the results, you have apply them separately.   No whole-array trickery here.

Comment: Ok thanks, I can turn [[0,2], [1]] in [[True, False, True], [False, True, False]] but I'm not sure if that can help

Comment: You'd still have to apply the boolean masks one at a time if you want the result to individual arrays of varying length.  A boolean mask returns a flat result regardless of its shape.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a recursive lookup function like:

```py
def nested_array_getter(arr, idx_or_list):
    if isinstance(idx_or_list, int):
        return arr[idx_or_list]
    return [nested_array_getter(arr, el) for el in idx_or_list]

nested_array_getter(a,b)
# returns [[1, 3], [2]]
```

Generalize to lookup slices or masks if needed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was more looking for a "whole-array trickery" but it seems that it does not exist one

Comment: Indeed I don't think numpy has a util for that

Comment: You can extend the ndarray class for that btw

Comment: Well this is *definitely* going to be slower

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga of course you're adding some overhead, but we don't know what's the final utility of these look ups

Comment: The OP already had a solution to.compste against with the list comprehension

Comment: Not at the time I put my answer